# Why does SQLAlchemy insert expression values() method function differently when executing in one statement or two?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm working through the SQLAlchemy core tutorial (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/tutorial.html) and found a strange behavior. In the Insert Expressions section they first create a basic insert expression and print it.

```
>>> ins = users.insert()
>>> str(ins)
'INSERT INTO users (id, name, fullname) VALUES (:id, :name, :fullname)'
```

They then perform the same operation, adding values to specific columns, which limits the number of columns in the expression to those listed in the `values()` call.

```
>>> ins = users.insert().values(name='jack', fullname='Jack Jones')
>>> str(ins)
'INSERT INTO users (name, fullname) VALUES (:name, :fullname)'
```

Why is it that if I take the second version and perform it in 2 lines instead of 1, the `values()` call doesn't take?

```
>>> ins = users.insert()
>>> ins.values(name='jack', fullname='Jack Jones')
>>> str(ins)
'INSERT INTO users (id, name, fullname) VALUES (:id, :name, :fullname)'
```

I know the `values()` call is truly not doing anything because the I tested the `params` value from a `ins.compile().params` call and they are all `None` in the version in 2 lines.

```
>>> ins = users.insert().values(name='jack', fullname='Jack Jones')
>>> ins.compile().params
{'fullname': 'Jack Jones', 'name': 'jack'}

>>> ins = users.insert()
>>> ins.values(name='jack', fullname='Jack Jones')
>>> ins.compile().params
{'fullname': None, 'password': None, 'id': None, 'name': None}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between these two:

```
>>> ins = users.insert().values(name='jack', fullname='Jack Jones')
>>> ins.compile().params
{'fullname': 'Jack Jones', 'name': 'jack'}

>>> ins = users.insert()
>>> ins.values(name='jack', fullname='Jack Jones')
>>> ins.compile().params
{'fullname': None, 'password': None, 'id': None, 'name': None}
```

is that you are not saving the returned value of `ins` in the second case.
I haven't tested, but to make them equivalent, it should be something like:

```
>>> ins = users.insert()
>>> ins = ins.values(name='jack', fullname='Jack Jones')
```

Otherwise, what you do with `ins.values` just vanishes

Comment: it happens to all of us, and all the time ;)